# simplexml_load_file give didn't work read node which contains url with query strings?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am working with simple project to read data from xml and save into database. But I got one problem while reading XML file. Some brief is below:

My **parser.php** code:

```
if (file_exists('zero.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('zero.xml');

    echo $xml->productURL;
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
```

and **zero.xml** file contain:

```
<product sku="107">
    <price>6999</price>
    <productURL>https://www.example.com/in/open.pl?user_id=2&b=96</productURL>
</product>
```

Upon run code didn't got any output just warnings.

> EntityRef: expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlsvr2012\parser.php on
>   line 31

When I replace "&" operator in url

> user_id=2&b=96

with ; or : then this give me output. But that is not exact url format which is not acceptible. I don't why this is not working with & operator. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks @salathe  &amp is good. Little issue is my server side code get xml data file from client daily bases. I want something which do same job automatically to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding little solution to salathe answer not ideal but will work. You may have to load file contents and perform find and replace operation `str_replace()` like `& -> &amp;` and pass refined contents to simple xml parser

```
<?php

$path_to_file = 'path/to/the/file.xml';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("&",",&amp;",$file_contents);

simplexml_load_string($file_contents);

?>
```

Hope this may help!

Answer (score 0):

A bare `&` is not valid XML character data, since it is used to denote the start of a named entity.  You have several options, including enclosing the value in a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) block, or my preferred choice is to use the `&amp;` entity like `?user_id=2&amp;b=96`

**Entity example**

```
<productURL>https://www.example.com/in/open.pl?user_id=2&amp;b=96</productURL>
```

**CDATA example**

```
<productURL><![CDATA[https://www.example.com/in/open.pl?user_id=2&b=96]]></productURL>
```

The XML spec says the following on this matter:

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " & " and " < " respectively.
>
> – http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax

Comment: Thanks @salathe &amp is good. Little issue is my server side code get xml data file from client daily bases. I want something which do same job automatically to fix this